# Laravel 5.2 Auth Session expires in seconds after login

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the very basic Laravel 5.2 Authentication to Register and Login.
After login and redirect, it just a few seconds then Session expire again and I have to login.

I have increased the Session Lifetime to:

```
'lifetime' => 360
```

Also The token expires so quick just a few seconds and it gone.
Any advice !

Comment: could it be php is expiring the session? What is your session life time in php.ini?

Comment: session driver used?

Comment: I'm using Session driver: file, also I used cookie, with the same issue

Comment: in php.ini: session.gc_maxlifetime=1440